# Unable to upload file using selenium with python: ElementNotInteractableException. Element is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have read all the available answers on stackoverflow related to my query but no answers is solution of my problem. I am trying to upload a document from desktop using python script but script gets failed in between with Exception. Scripts throws Exception in following python code

```
frame1 = driver.find_element_by_id("BrowseButton")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)
document_to_attach = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//object[@class='swfupload']")))


document_to_attach.send_keys(r"C:\Users\Desktop\sample.msg")
```

Exception is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <object id="SWFUpload_0" class="swfupload" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

HTML Code corresponding to this element is

```
    <iframe style="position: relative; top: 5px;" border="0" src="DocumentUploadForm.jsp?DocID=21UZZZQ5UGKEZN5OBTZQ51JZR1BJD3ZZ&amp;maxNumFiles=3&amp;Time=1584360999619&quot;" name="BrowseButton" id="BrowseButton" scrolling="no" width="100" height="32" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>

    <object id="SWFUpload_0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swfupload/swfupload.swf" class="swfupload" style="" width="20" height="20">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="movie" value="swfupload/swfupload.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="flashvars" value="movieName=SWFUpload_0&amp;uploadURL=%2Fhome%2Fgold%2Fjsp%2FDocumentUploadReceiver.jsp%3FTWCSESSIONID%3Drmgw946kr5mi46v8srwuewbs&amp;useQueryString=false&amp;requeueOnError=false&amp;httpSuccess=&amp;assumeSuccessTimeout=0&amp;params=&amp;filePostName=Filedata&amp;fileTypes=*.*&amp;fileTypesDescription=All%20Files&amp;fileSizeLimit=64%20MB&amp;fileUploadLimit=3&amp;fileQueueLimit=3&amp;debugEnabled=false&amp;buttonImageURL=%2Fhome%2Fgold%2Fjsp%2F&amp;buttonWidth=20&amp;buttonHeight=20&amp;buttonText=&amp;buttonTextTopPadding=0&amp;buttonTextLeftPadding=0&amp;buttonTextStyle=color%3A%20%23000000%3B%20font-size%3A%2016pt%3B&amp;buttonAction=-110&amp;buttonDisabled=false&amp;buttonCursor=-2"></object>
```

This is the image[image: I want to send the path of this file on in the image after document to attach]

Manually if I open website and uploading the document, it is successfully browsing document from desktop and uploading it. When I am using selenium script with Firefox Web Browser , it is giving the above exception. While running automation script, if manually I am trying to click this element than also I am unable to click it and it appears as an image on browser.

**I think it may be related to Flash object or some plugins or something else.**
What is the reason behind this exception and how to solve this exception

Comment: Selenium can't see inside a Flash object because it's not HTML. You may be able to see the traffic generated when you manually enter a file and upload it and then spoof that traffic with your desired filename, etc.

Comment: Can you look through your HTML and search for tag `input` with `value="file"`, are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind the exception is due to flash used by website.So added the following line of code-

```
firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile, executable_path=r'drivers\geckodriver.exe')
```

Also after it, automation script was not giving path using send_keys and hence found solution to use `pyautogui` library or `autoit` library. Following code is used for this purpose-

```
frame1 = driver.find_element_by_id("BrowseButton")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)
document_to_attach = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//object[@class='swfupload']")))
document_to_attach.click()
import time
time.sleep(5)
import autoit
autoit.control_focus("Open", "")
autoit.control_set_text("Open", "Edit1", r"C:\Users\Desktop\sample.msg")
autoit.control_click("Open", "Button1")
```

You have to install autoit module in case if you do not have it by `pip install autoit`

Answer (score 0):

Use `presence_of_element_located`. The element you are sending text to may not be clickable.

If that does not work try the commented out like that contains `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

frame1 = driver.find_element_by_id("BrowseButton")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)
document_to_attach = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//object[@class='swfupload']")))
#document_to_attach = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//object[@class='swfupload']")))


document_to_attach.send_keys(r"C:\Users\Desktop\sample.msg")
```

Comment: I have already use presence of element but it is not working. I have tried maximum possible solutions

Comment: I think it is related to flash that this website uses

Comment: I have also tried WebdriverWait but this is not  working

Comment: how to achieve it